# Invalidating a type provider with FSharpChecker

Tags: f#, type-providers

I'm using [FSharpChecker](http://fsharp.github.io/FSharp.Compiler.Service/reference/microsoft-fsharp-compiler-sourcecodeservices-fsharpchecker.html) to type-check some code on the fly but I cannot figure out how to properly handle type providers. I'm doing:

```
let checker = FSharpChecker.Create()
let tempDir = 
    let d = Path.Combine(Path.GetTempPath(), Path.GetRandomFileName())
    Directory.CreateDirectory(d) |> ignore
    d
let dummyFile = "dummy.fsx"

let Check source template =
    let args = 
        [|
            yield "-r:" + Path.Combine(root, "FSharp.Core.dll")
            yield "-r:" + Path.Combine(root, "mscorlib.dll")
            yield "-r:" + Path.Combine(root, "System.Numerics.dll") //not sure why I need this
            yield "--noframework"
            for r in refs do yield "-r:" + Path.Combine(root, r)
        |]
    try
        File.WriteAllText(Path.Combine(tempDir, "inputForTheTypeProvider.txt"), template)

        let file = Path.Combine(tempDir, dummyFile)
        let opts = checker.GetProjectOptionsFromScript(file, source, otherFlags = args) |> Async.RunSynchronously
        let parse = checker.ParseFileInProject(file, source, opts) |> Async.RunSynchronously
        let answer = checker.CheckFileInProject(parse, file, 0, source, opts) |> Async.RunSynchronously
        match answer with
        | FSharpCheckFileAnswer.Succeeded check ->
            TypeCheckResults.Success { Check = check; Parse = parse }
        | FSharpCheckFileAnswer.Aborted ->
            TypeCheckResults.Failure (sprintf "%A" answer)
    with
    | ex ->
        TypeCheckResults.InternalError (ex.Message, ex.StackTrace)
```

`source` contains the F# code and uses the type provider. Now the problem is the checker works as expected on the first pass but when I change the contents of `"inputForTheTypeProvider.txt"` the previous version will be used still until I reinstantiate `FSharpChecker`. I'm guessing some kind of cached version of the output of the type provider is used on the subsequent passes but I have no idea how to invalidate it. I've already tried using `checker.InvalidateAll` and `checker.NotifyProjectCleaned(opts)` to no avail.